# Facebook SDK + SlidingMenu SDK = Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook, sdk, slidingmenu

So I have added the Facebook SDK and the SlidingMenu SDK into my Android project, however I am getting those nasty "Jar mismatch" errors.

I have already removed the `android-support-v4.jar` file from my **libs** folder, yet the error persists.

Any ideas on how to fix this?
(I have also tried deleting the files from the folders, but I get the 'file not found' errors)

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JOvg.png

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Delete the `android-support-v4.jar` from the *SlidingMenu* library. And copy the `android-support-v4.jar` file from the Facebook SDK's libs folder and paste it in to your *SlidingMenu's* libs folder.

And then refresh the SlidingMenu project and  finally *clean all projects* after doing the above.

Comment: @MegaBubbletea: Glad to have helped. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the support library from both library projects and re-add it to your project.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the remove the `android-support-v4.jar` file from the libs folder from your project.

Good Luck.