# JAR Mismatach ! Fix your dependency error while using two libs

Tags: android, jar, android-support-library

I have created an app and need to use two diffrent android support lib as methods I have used are not  avialable in  one lib.One lib I have used is **ABS** for sliding menu  and second one is **ActionBarSherelock**  and both are using different android support lib.When I use both in my project I got this error.

LogCat    :

```
Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
        \[2014-01-13 11:26:17 - phoneCall\] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
        \[2014-01-13 11:26:17 - phoneCall\] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
        \[2014-01-13 11:26:17 - phoneCall\] Versions found are:
        \[2014-01-13 11:26:17 - phoneCall\] Path: /root/AndroidHome/AndroidWorkspace/ActionBarSherlock/libs/android-support-v4.jar
        \[2014-01-13 11:26:17 - phoneCall\]     Length: 385685
        \[2014-01-13 11:26:17 - phonecall\]     SHA-1: 48c94ae70fa65718b382098237806a5909bb096e
        \[2014-01-13 11:26:17 - phone91\] Path: /root/AndroidHome/AndroidWorkspace/ABS/libs/android-support-v4.jar
        \[2014-01-13 11:26:17 - phoneCall\]     Length: 484258
        \[2014-01-13 11:26:17 - phoneCall\]     SHA-1: bd6479f5dd592790607e0504e66e0f31c2b4d308
        \[2014-01-13 11:26:17 - phoneCall\] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
```

I have referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994237/facebook-sdk-slidingmenu-sdk-jar-mismatch-fix-your-dependencies) solution and tried to resolve but it is showing  error in mainactivity on

```
 import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
 import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
 import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
```

Please tell me how to resolve this .

Comment: Try by removing  android.support.v4.jar of your application.Then clean and build.

Comment: Have you tried referring your main project's android support v4 to your library project instead of copying it? I mean by deleting the v4 support from the other project then, go to its build path. Select the Libraries tab. You'll find "Add Jar". Click that button then choose your main project's v4 support library. If you haven't tried this, I'll put it as answer.

Comment: @vida what I have done  till now is  I have removed jar from ABS and copid jar of action bar sherelock in it.But then my project required some classes which are not availabe in that support libs and have deleted projects jar already .

Comment: @Bansal_Sneha I see. So you are using 2 different versions of v4 support lib? Do you know what specific versions of v4 support are you using? Also, what's the specific error in MainActivity?

Comment: @vida both lib showing revise version 19 and when I deleted  jar of abs and copied support lib from action shereloack bar  to make same I am getting error mentioned in question

Comment: @Bansal_Sneha Could you try the steps I have indicated above and tell me if the mismatch error still occur? Instead of copying, do the "Add jar" instead.

Comment: @vida which jar should I add .Jar of ABS or Jar of action bar sherelock lib ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45091/discussion-between-vida-and-bansal-sneha)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **android-support-v4.jar** in the application and in the **ActionBarSherlock** app are of different versions. Just delete that jar from your app and copy the new one from ActionBarSherlock library project to make the version same.

Comment: I have already deleted jar from app.That two jars are in ABS and actionbar libs

Comment: @Bansal_Sneha What is your app name? Your error is saying that the lib of ABS and actionbar are not same, so make them same.

Comment: ABS ans actionbarsherelock  are libraries

Comment: @Bansal_Sneha so copy the jar from ActionBarSherlock and paste it in ABS and also in your app, so that the all three apps have the same jar.

Comment: App does not have jar I have deleted  jar from it

Comment: copy it from actionbar and paste it in your app and in ABS lib.

Comment: I have done that as I have mentioned in question .After doing that I have got error in my project that import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
 import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
 import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout are not  available

Comment: Can I copy classes from one android support lib to other support  lib ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45090/discussion-between-bansal-sneha-and-amit-singh)

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to Delete Android’s default support library if exists from the project,

By default, Eclipse adds Android’s Support library to the project. We don’t want to use this library for this project. This library will be available in the folder “libs” in the name “android-support-v4.jar“. Delete this jar file from the “libs” folder

Ref Point Number 6 : http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/implement-swiping-between-tabs-with-viewpager-in-action-bar-using-sherlock-library/

Comment: I thought there should be one jar per project  and if I am right there   will be still mismatch happen as I have  two different jar in to lib's.

Comment: First try your self and then tell me. I got same error and I tried this step, It is working at my side.

Comment: same error as . ihave copied ABS jar  in project but Actionbar sherelock lib still have different lib

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that `android-support-v4.jar` in the application and in the `ActionBarSherlock` app are same so please copy android-support-v4.jar from ABS lib and use it in yours project as well.

follow these steps,

1. Go to ABS Project's lib folder and copy android-support-v4.jar file
2. Paste .jar file into your current project
3. Clean and refresh the project